# Global Exception Handlers in Java

Tags: java, android, exception

I am thinking of setting up a global, default Exception handler for my (Android) Mobile application(which uses Java syntax) using `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)` call. I am thinking of just displaying an Alert Dialog with appropriate message to the user.

Are there any gotchas, caveats and rules that one needs to follow when setting  `DefaultExceptionHandlers`? Any best practices like making sure that the process is killed, full stack trace is written to logs etc. ?

Links to documentation, tutorials etc. that can throw some light on this are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The name is a bit misleading, because using that method will set a default exception handler for **all** threads.
- Make sure no exceptions can be thrown from your exception handler.
- If you're doing GUI stuff from your exception handler, make sure you're doing it from the right thread.
- An uncaught exception will only stop the thread where the exception took place, if that also causes the process to terminate depends on any other threads that might be running.

Comment: "If you're doing GUI stuff from your exception handler, make sure you're doing it from the right thread." What does this mean?

Comment: It means that GUI stuff should be done in the EDT thread (using `invokeLater` if necessary) Otherwise weird things can happen.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem with creating a global exception handler is you may get stuck in a loop of exceptions - some exceptions will be thrown repeatedly unless a program is terminated.

If you mean that when an exception is thrown, a message is displayed then the app is terminated, then you'll be fine.

Comment: If in my uncaughtException method, I just display an AlertDialog will the Runtime kill/terminate the process automatically or will I have to be explicit with this?

Comment: If you display an AlertDialog in the normal flow of code, is it automatically killed off?