# Android and Flurry ExceptionHandler

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

This question is for people that has experience using flurry sdk in android applications. This sdk installs a custom exception handler. I am not satisfied with the detail of information that is logged by flurry and I would like to install my own ExceptionHandler while using flurry. Sadly the ExceptionHandler is unique per thread. Is there anyone that has found a wordaround?

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you initialize Flurry first and then set your own exception handler via "Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)" ? More info on default uncaught exception handlers here: [Global Exception Handlers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815938/global-exception-handlers-in-java)

-Dan